# Different numbers between count points in polygon and select by location

Tags: qgis, select, count

When I'm running the points in polygon in QGIS I get one result (125) and when I try to select the points to extract as a layer, select by location, I get another result (213).

If I extract the points and re-map them, they all seem to fall within the polygon boundary, any reason as to why they might be different, and which one is more of a credible source?

Running QGIS 3.4.9

Comment: Sorry, it has to be asked...are you sure you are using the same point files in both methods?  Or maybe you have two different point files with some points directly under others?

Comment: @GBG Yes I've checked that again. I believe it has something to do with count points in polygon method, that requires a point to be completely within the polygon boundary, where select by location selects points where any part of the point may be touching the polygon. Would appreciate if someone can confirm this for me.

Comment: Look at the points that are in the larger set, and which are also not in the smaller set. Then report back about any patterns you find.

Comment: You can test/confirm this yourself.  Create a new polygon.  Use Vector-Geometry Tools-Extract Nodes to create points that rest on your polygon.  Then use your selection method and Points in Polygon and compare the results.